# ClassNotFoundException: AbstractEndpoint after updating spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

### Introduction

I am getting the following exception after the team upgraded our POM to use more updated spring boot libraries.

Specifically we went from the following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

To the following:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Basically from **1.5.9.RELEASE** to **2.0.3.RELEASE** .

Specifically, the following exception takes place during testing.

### Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.mbak.swagger.SwaggerConfiguration.swaggerConfig
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.prometheus.client.spring.boot.PrometheusEndpointConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:726)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/AbstractEndpoint
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Class.java)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
[sg-template-store] 13:42:38.210 INFO  [traceId:-] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4c56e671: startup date [Mon Jul 02 13:42:36 CEST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5bb661e0
[sg-template-store] 13:42:38.211 WARN  [traceId:-] SpringApplication - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.prometheus.client.spring.boot.PrometheusEndpointConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:726)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:889)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:875)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/AbstractEndpoint
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Class.java)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Post your whole pom

Comment: exclude `simpleclient_spring_boot` dependency from your dependencies and any explicit use you might have. Full coordinates: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_spring_boot

Comment: Run a maven update from your IDE

Comment: See https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/issues/299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in `org.mbak.swagger.SwaggerConfiguration` is referencing `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint`. This class exists in Spring Boot 1.x but was removed in 2.0.

Presumably `SwaggerConfiguration` is from a dependency, otherwise you would have had a compile failure. If a Spring Boot 2 compatible version of the dependency that contains `SwaggerConfiguration` is available, you should upgrade. Failing that you’ll have to stop using it until such a version is available.